# adding datasets data as one sum json

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am new to charts.js, and am creating a doughnut chart that shows the percentages of members according to their seniority. All works well, except I want to total the number of members in the center of the doughnut. I am using a plugin called doughnutlabel.js. The data is a json encode from a php search. here is the code.

```js
$('#exampleAccordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext('2d');
  var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: <?php echo json_encode($CDC_time);?>,
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: ["#5969ff", "#ff407b", "#25d5f2", "#ffc750", "#2ec551", "#7040fa", "#ff004e"],
        data: <?php echo json_encode($CDC_employees);?>,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        doughnutlabel: {
          labels: [{
            text: getTotal,
            font: {
              size: '50'
            },
            color: 'grey'
          }, {
            text: 'Members',
            font: {
              size: '40'
            },
            color: 'grey'
          }]
        },
        labels: [{
          render: 'label',
          fontSize: '12',
          position: 'outside'
        }, {
          render: 'percentage',
          fontColor: '#000000',
          fontSize: '12',
          precision: 0
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
    }
  });
});
var getTotal = function(myChart2) {
  var sum = myChart2.config.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  
  return `${sum}`;
}
```

this is the result
[image: donut chart]

as you can see, 96 is the number that should show in the middle.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be adding string representations of numbers. When you add "1" + "2" as strings the result is "12".  You may need to incorporate some type conversion from string to number at the appropriate place in your code. I recommend `Number()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: Also worth mentioning - JSON is always a string.